# Installing Agile Toolkit

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

Could someone please explain to me, how do I get Agile Toolkit up and running ? I've cloned atk4 repository to my machine, moved it to my MAMP's webroot. When I access it from my browser `http://localhost/my_app` I see 403 error.

Does it mean there's no installation file ? And everything has to be setup via some *.cfg file ? Can't find a proper tutorial on how to do so.

Or there's an installation process just like in other frameworks and it's just my MAMP is not configured correctly ?

EDIT:
Sorry, I guess I had a wrong downloaded archive. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an author of Agile Toolkit and for the convenience of the new users, I'm now packaging 4.3 into an archive with installer.

Go to http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/ and click download.

There seem to be some hiccups with Windows install which I'm trying to address. Please discuss any problems in this group:

http://forum.agiletoolkit.org/